# How to run the next stage even if the previous stage is rejected or cancelled in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

How can i run the stage automatically even if the previous stage is rejected by the approver or else cancelled ? Even if the previous stage status is Failed then also i need to execute next stage .